# Has anyone had problems applying Pandas's 'any()' method to a large DataFrame? What's going on?

Tags: python, pandas, any

I am working on a machine learning project that aims to predict outages on an electrical grid. I organize the data into a big Pandas DataFrame, and create columns in the DataFrame that indicate whether a specific meter has a voltage lower than a given threshold, assigning the columns a value "True" if so, "False" otherwise.

```
        # Define a lambda function to test whether or not a meters Vin is below threshold
        g = lambda x: bool(x < outage_threshold)

        # Add a column to the DataFrame to indicate whether or not this meter is down
        data_id['Status %d' % meter_id] = data_id['Vin %d' % meter_id].apply(g)
```

This code works. However, I want to create a column called 'outage' that indicates whether any meter in that row (at that time) has a low voltage, and that is not working. If even one meter column has a value of true, I want 'outage' to be true.

To do this, I use the DataFrame's any() method:

```
    # Add a column which indicates whether any of the meters are out
    data_all['Outage'] = data_all.any(axis=1, skipna=True, bool_only=True)
```

On small DataFrames, the code generally works well. However, on larger DataFrames (several hundred thousand rows, several hundred columns), it will sometimes return "False" in rows in which it should be "True." For example, here is the output from the last few rows of one run:

Last three rows of data set:

```
                     cloudCover  Vin 1061  Vout 1061  Current 1061  Mode 1061  \
2014-03-31 23:57:00        0.87         0          0             0          0   
2014-03-31 23:58:00        0.87         0          0             0          0   
2014-03-31 23:59:00        0.87         0          0             0          0   

                    Status 1061  Vin 1063  Vout 1063  Current 1063  Mode 1063  \
2014-03-31 23:57:00        True      2495        117             0          0   
2014-03-31 23:58:00        True      2495        117             0          0   
2014-03-31 23:59:00        True      2495        117             0          0   

                      ...   Mode 867  Vin 869  Vout 869  Current 869  \
2014-03-31 23:57:00   ...          1     2553      1590           52   
2014-03-31 23:58:00   ...          1     2553      1590           52   
2014-03-31 23:59:00   ...          1     2553      1590           52   

                     Mode 869 Vin 1018  Vout 1018  Current 1018  Mode 1018  \
2014-03-31 23:57:00         1     2583       2547             0          0   
2014-03-31 23:58:00         1     2583       2547             0          0   
2014-03-31 23:59:00         1     2583       2547             0          0   

                     Outage  
2014-03-31 23:57:00   False  
2014-03-31 23:58:00   False  
2014-03-31 23:59:00   False  

[3 rows x 617 columns]
Value Counts for outage:
False    96432
True     33166
dtype: int64
```

In these first three rows of the data, there is an outage in Meter 2054 indicated by the "True" values, but the 'Outage' column of the DataFrame reads "False."

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on?

Thanks so much,

Sam

Comment: Create a reproducible example for N rows, and increase N until you tickle this issue. Then post that code here.

Comment: you are using `data_all.all` not `DataFrame.any`, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Wow, that is somewhat embarrassing but you are absolutely right. Thanks m.wasowski!

Comment: I am still having problems - will share code above. Thanks for all your help. I will work on a reproducable example, smci - thanks.

Comment: RESOLVED: I was making another, equally clowny, mistake and calling all() before calling fillna so many of the rows were blank. Thanks all!